# Are there kits to add plug on neutral bars to existing breaker boxes?

Tags: circuit-breaker, gfci, afci

I have an existing square D non-plug on neutral breaker box (believe it's a SO, about 20 years old).

My questions is if there is a install kit to either add the neutral plug in rail or replace the load center to include the plug in rail in the breaker box.

[image]

Comment: You would have to replace the whole bus assembly,  I guess that's possible, but I'm not sure if it's allowed.

Comment: You can get anything that's available in plug-on neutral in pigtail neutral as well\

Comment: Take a clear picture of the label under your pinkie finger and the model of the load center should be less of a guessing game.

Comment: I was hoping that I could replace the whole bus assembly and skip the box (I hate drywall work).

Comment: Are those yellow labels flammable?

Comment: Labels are Romex sheathing.

Answer (score 1):

Spoke with Schneider (square D) today and there are no conversion kits to add a plug-on neutral rail for any of their 3 lines. (picture is QO line).

They were thinking about a conversion kit, but lawyers said no because it brought up too many user hazards and possible lawsuits.

I don't think he was supposed to mention this, but current plan is to end of life the pigtailed breakers by 2030 (QO line, unsure about the Homeline).